# Setfacl - not supported

Tags: linux, configuration, acl, ext4

I am trying to give acl access to oracle logs  but it is giving the Operation not supported error.

```
[oracle@localhost  AdminServer]$ setfacl -m u:ruis:rx logs/ 
setfacl: logs/: Operation not supported
```

Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: How is your FS mounted? For some cases acl needs to be activated on mounting time.

Comment: /dev/sdb1               /u01                    ext4    defaults        1 2

Comment: [root@localhost u01]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted

Comment: Can anyone help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACL has to be explicit activated on ext-filesystems. Therefor you should have something like

```
/dev/sdb1 /u01 ext4 defaults,acl 1 2
```

inside your `/etc/fstab`.